# Difference of ee.Reducer.sensSlope and ee.Reducer.linearFit

Tags: google-earth-engine

My purpose is to calculate the multi-year NDVI trend, I noticed that  ee.Reducer.sensSlope, ee.Reducer.linearFit  and ee.Reducer.linearRegression can be used, how can I differentiate them? Also, data may be missing in some years and I want null values to be excluded from the analysis, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read up on some of this in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/reducers_regression).

> The simplest linear regression reducer is linearFit() which computes
> the least squares estimate of a linear function of one variable with a
> constant term. For a more flexible approach to linear modelling, use
> one of the linear regression reducers which allow for a variable
> number of independent and dependent variables. linearRegression()
> implements ordinary least squares regression(OLS).

It doesn't cover `sensSlope()`, but in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theil%E2%80%93Sen_estimator) you've got a description of that.

> This estimator can be computed efficiently, and is insensitive to
> outliers. It can be significantly more accurate than non-robust simple
> linear regression (least squares) for skewed and heteroskedastic data,
> and competes well against least squares even for normally distributed
> data in terms of statistical power.[10] It has been called "the most
> popular nonparametric technique for estimating a linear trend".

On `null` values: If you're applying this to imagery you don't have any `null` values, but masked pixels. They will not influence your results.